# Ancestor/Parent of objects in bulk upload

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a simple model whose instances I create usually with an default parent key (parent is no real model). It's the same approach as described in the [GAE tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore)

```
def simple_parent_key():
    return db.Key.from_path('simple', 'pathsimple')

class Simple(db.Model):
    """Basic simple model"""
    name = db.StringProperty()
```

I normally create an object in a post request like this:

```
class AddSimple(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        simple = Simple(parent=simple_parent_key())
        simple.name = self.request.get('name')
```

Now I want to add some objects using the bulk upload method of GAE. The problem is, I didn't find a way to specify the parent/ancestor key for the bulk upload. Objects will get created without a parent, and all queries using the parent key will not return those new objects. Thus breaking the consistency.

Is there a way to specify the parent key in bulk upload files?

Here is a part of the bulkloader.yaml file:

```
transformers:
- kind: Simple
  connector: csv
  property_map:
    - property: name
      external_name: name
```

The upload is working, but does not have any parent key, which is what I want.

Any hints welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Use create_deep_key to create keys with parents [transform.create_deep_key](http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py). It's a little tricky to use it. I have successfully create parent keys, using xml instead of csv

Here's an example of the property key in the bulkloader.yaml :

```
     - property: __key__ 
       external_name: key
       import_transform: transform.create_deep_key(('parentKind', 'parentKeyName'),
                                                   ('entityKind', transform.CURRENT_PROPERTY))
```

Hope it helps...